Ambiguity regarding the solution for $\int \sec^2x\tan x dx$
I had my first integration test today. There, I met up with a integrand that gives two different functions as a whole.
Taking $t=\tan x$:-
$$\int \sec^2x\tan x dx = \int t \ dt=\frac{t^2}{2}+C=\frac{\tan^2x}{2}+C$$
Taking $t=\sec x$:-
$$\int \sec^2x\tan x dx = \int t \ dt=\frac{t^2}{2}+C=\frac{\sec^2x}{2}+C$$
Which is the correct answer to the question?
Are there any other examples except $\csc^2x\cot x$ and this one?

This (type of) question is a megaduplicate, and the answer is that both are correct, since their difference is constant.

Two answer are basically the same since $\tan^2(x)+1=\sec^2(x)$, you can just change the constant of the first to get the second.

Does that extra half from $\frac{\tan^2 x +1}{2}$ go away along with the $C$? @Tri

$\frac{\sec^2x}{2}+C=\frac{\tan^2x}{2}+D$, for $D=C+\frac12$.

@Gwen I am not sure what you meant by going away, but indefinite integral gives you a family of functions, not just one. So technically you can change C in the first to C+1/2 without any problems, if that is what you meant
